# Euler method and bisection method

Tags: real-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, matlab, bisection, eulers-method

I'd like to solve the equation 
$$ \phi''(x) = \lambda \sin (\phi(x)) $$
where $x \in (0,L)$, $\phi'(0) = 0$, $\phi'(L) = 0$.

Let $ \psi = \phi'$ and
$$ \phi'(x) - \psi(x) = 0$$
$$ \psi'(x) - \lambda \sin (\phi(x)) = 0$$

for $x \in (0,L)$ and $\psi(0) = 0, \phi(0) = \phi_0.$

Can anybody help me to find $\phi_0 $ numerically such that $\phi'(L) = 0$ holds?

I received the advice to compute the solution of $(\phi, \psi)$ with the explicit Euler method for $\phi_0 = 1.5$ and $\phi_0 = 3$ and to use the method of bisection to compute $\phi_0$.

In addition, I received the following values:

- Number of steps (bisection): $2^6$
- Length of steps (Euler): L/100
- L = 5
- $\lambda$ = 2

Thanks for any help!

EDIT:

In the meantime, I coded a bit. I added your functions as well as an implementation of Euler and bisection. See what I did so far.

Now my problem is to connect your functions with my functions. Can you please help a bit? (For example, it's not clear to me where to define the function, and it's not clear to me when calling your functions "model" and "omegaL"...)

```
funtion x = eubisect()
    u = bisection(f, a, b, N, eps_step, eps_abs)

function dotu = model(t,u)
    lambda = 2;
    dotu = [ u(2); lambda*sin(u(1)) ]
end

function omegaL= f(phi0)
    L = 5;
    N = 100;
    t,u = Euler(model, 0, L, N, [phi0,0])
    omegaL = u(end,2)
end

function [t, y] = Euler(f, a, b, N, y0)
    clear t % Clears old time steps and
    clear y % y values from previous runs
    %a=0; % Initial time
    %b=1; % Final time
    %N=10; % Number of time steps
    %y0=0; % Initial value y(a)
    h=(b-a)/N; % Time step
    t(1)=a;
    y(1)=y0;
    for n=1:N % For loop, sets next t,y values
        t(n+1)=t(n)+h;
        y(n+1)=y(n)+h*f(t(n),y(n)); % Calls the function f(t,y)=dy/dt
    end
    %plot(t,y)
    %title(['Euler Method using N=',num2str(N),' steps'])
end


function [ r ] = bisection( f, a, b, N, eps_step, eps_abs )
    % Check that that neither end-point is a root
    % and if f(a) and f(b) have the same sign, throw an exception.

    if ( abs(f(a)) < eps_abs )
    r = a;
    return;
    elseif ( abs(f(b)) < eps_abs )
    r = b;
    return;
    elseif ( f(a) * f(b) > 0 )
        error( 'f(a) and f(b) do not have opposite signs' );
    end

    % We will iterate N times and if a root was not
    % found after N iterations, an exception will be thrown.

    for k = 1:N
        % Find the mid-point
        c = (a + b)/2;

        % Check if we found a root or whether or not
        % we should continue with:
        %          [a, c] if f(a) and f(c) have opposite signs, or
        %          [c, b] if f(c) and f(b) have opposite signs.

        if ( abs(f(c)) < eps_abs )
            r = c;
            return;
        elseif ( f(c)*f(a) < 0 )
            b = c;
        else
            a = c;
        end

        % If |b - a| < eps_step, check whether or not
        %       |f(a)| < |f(b)| and |f(a)| < eps_abs and return 'a', or
        %       |f(b)| < eps_abs and return 'b'.

        if ( b - a < eps_step )
            if ( abs( f(a) ) < abs( f(b) ) && abs( f(a) ) < eps_abs )
                r = a;
                return;
            elseif ( abs( f(b) ) < eps_abs )
                r = b;
                return;
            end
        end
    end

    error( 'the method did not converge' );
end
```

Comment: This is the physical pendulum seen from the upper, unstable equilibrium point. The stable point is at $ϕ=\pi$ so that for $ϕ_0\approx\pi$ you get period $2\pi$ and for $ϕ_0\approx0$ you get arbitrarily large periods. $L$ has to be a multiple of the half-period, so $L=5>\pi$ is admissible.

Comment: Yeah very cool! You knew this, but how is it possible to see the answer without knowing it in advance? Just try some values? (If yes, do you have any code on Matlab ?)

Comment: These are basic facts on the pendulum equation. What do you know about the single shooting method? In matlab you would normally use the boundary value problem solver, but then there would be no bisection method be needed.

Comment: Ok :) 

No, by "using Matlab", I meant that I implement the Euler and bisection methods and that I try, try and try to get $\phi_0 = \pi$ :)

Comment: Then please document what you already programmed and computed.

Comment: Thanks for your answer below - I just saw it. I didn't program anything yet, but with your help below, I'll do it now :)

Comment: Note that this is just the idea, and you have to use an Euler loop instead of ode45. I tried to test with octave, but no success, the graph was done with python.

Comment: You can not get $\phi_0=\pi$, corresponding to one of the constant solutions, with bisection as bracketing method as that is outside the initial interval $[1.5, 3]$.

Comment: omega like velocity of phi, L because it is the value at L. Euler should also take a function parameter. Euler will take the place of ode45 in the shooting function f.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/77613/discussion-between-dman-and-lutzl).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are to apply the single shooting method.

You already got the first order system

```
function dotu = model(t,u)
    lambda = 2;
    dotu = [ u(2); lambda*sin(u(1)) ]
end
```

Now define the shooting function

```
function omegaL= f(phi0)
    L = 5;
    t,u = ode45(model, [0,L], [phi0,0])
    omegaL = u(end,2)
end
```

and then call your bisection routine,

```
phi0 = bisection(f, 1.5, 3.0, 64).
```

---

Graph of function $f$, the root inside the given interval is close to $\phi_0=1.80132467093$. This is for a fairly exact integration of the IVP. For the rather inexact Euler method you will get a distorted graph and thus different roots.
[image]

Contents of `bvp_pendulum`, this is for octave, replace `endif, endfor, endfunction` with `end` if necessary.

```
function phi0 = bvp_pendulum()
    phi0 = bisection(@f, 1.5, 3.0, 64, 1e-10, 1e-10)
endfunction


function dotu = model(t,u)
    lambda = 2;
    dotu = [ u(2), lambda*sin(u(1)) ];
endfunction;

function [t,y] = Euler(f, a, b, N, y0)
    h=(b-a)/N; % Time step
    t(1)=a; % Initial time
    y(1,:)=y0; % Initial value y(a)
    for n=1:N % For loop, sets next t,y values
        t(n+1)=t(n)+h;
        y(n+1,:)=y(n,:)+h*f(t(n),y(n,:)); % Calls the function f(t,y)=dy/dt
    endfor;
endfunction;

function omegaL = f(phi0)
    L = 5; N=100;
    [t,u] = Euler(@model, 0, L, N, [phi0,0]);
    omegaL = u(end,2);
endfunction;

function r = bisection( f, a, b, N)
    % if f(a) and f(b) have the same sign, throw an exception.
    fa = f(a);
    fb = f(b)
    if ( fa * fb > 0 )
        error( 'f(a) and f(b) do not have opposite signs' );
    endif

    % We will iterate N times

    for k = 1:N
        % Find the mid-point
        c = (a + b)/2;

        % we continue with:
        %          [a, c] if f(a) and f(c) have opposite signs, or
        %          [c, b] if f(c) and f(b) have opposite signs.
        fc = f(c);
        disp([int2str(k),': new point c=',num2str(c,'%20.17f'),', f(c)=',num2str(fc,'%20.17f')]);
        if ( fc*fa < 0 )
            b = c; fb = fc;
        else
            a = c; fa = fc;
        endif

    endfor
    r = c;
endfunction
```

Comment: Thanks for this answer! I added an edit, maybe you can check this out? Thanks a lot!